# Lazy loading in Flask

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I am learning Flask and attempting to make a website like youtube. I have some experience with JS and know that you can write a script that will load an element only if it is in the viewport of the user.

Are there any built-in tools in Flask that I can use to achieve this or do I have to do this with JS? If that is the case, could you give me the code for that?

Comment: You're not thinking about what you're asking.  Scrolling like that is handled entirely in the browser.  The server is not involved, so Flask does not play a part.  It's all Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Only way to do it is through JS. I will assume you are not using any frameworks in the front-end. here is an example of vanilla JavaScript:
html

```
<body>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img class="lazy-image" data-src="image.jpg" alt="Lazy-loaded Image">
  </div>

  <script src="lazy-load.js"></script>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
const lazyImages = document.querySelectorAll('.lazy-image');

const options = {
  root: null, // Use the viewport as the root
  rootMargin: '0px', // No additional margin
  threshold: 0.2 // 20% of the image must be visible
};

const callback = (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      const image = entry.target;
      const src = image.getAttribute('data-src');

      if (src) {
        image.src = src;
        observer.unobserve(image);
      }
    }
  });
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

lazyImages.forEach(image => {
  observer.observe(image);
});
```